# How to enter a v8::Persistent<v8::Context> in a multithreaded environment?

Tags: v8, embedded-v8

I trying to setup a multithreaded environment there multiple v8::Isolate objects may be entered/exited constantly to compile and run some JavaScript code. I have a method that should compile and run som javascript code in a specific Isolate/Context:

```
void myclass::run(const std::string & code, v8::Persistsent<v8::Context> & con)
{
  boost::asio::io_service::strand & strand = this->_strand;
  // strand guarantee at most one handler will be executed concurrently
  strand.post([&]() {
    v8::Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(this->get_isolate());
    v8::HandleScope handle_scope(this->get_isolate());

    // This code below will compile but undefined is allways returned.
    // Because v8::Persistent<v8::Context> does not have any
    // "Enter/Exit" methods so is my attempt to create a Local handle instead.
    // However, as I said earlier, it does not work. Any idea how to fix it?

    v8::Local<v8::Context> context = v8::Local<v8::Context>::New(this->get_isolate(), con);
    v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context); // auto enter/leave. 


    // Compile the source code.
    v8::Local<v8::String> source = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(_isolate, code.c_str());

    v8::Local<v8::Script> script = v8::Script::Compile(source);

    v8::Local<v8::Value> result = script->Run();
    // result is allways undefined, what am I doing wrong?
  });
}
```

As you can see in the comments in the code however, it does not work. I simply want to just enter a specfic Isolate together with a Persistent. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your C++ looks right to me. Could there be an error in your Javascript? Using a TryCatch object will reveal any problems in your javascript code.